# Formatting Error in my Code C#

Tags: c#

I got an error when I copy the value of MyMiddlePart to NumberOfMonths
the error is InvalidCastException

```
string readMiddlePartSQL = "select distinct add_months(to_date('" +
                           My_StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + 
                           "','dd/mm/yyyy'), 1) - add_months(to_date('" +
                           My_EndDate.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy") + 
                           "','dd / mm / yyyy'),-1) 
                           from UNPAID_LEAVES_REQUEST";
OrderedDictionary MyMiddlePart = ew_ExecuteRow(readMiddlePartSQL);
float NumberOfMonths = Convert.ToSingle(MyMiddlePart);
```

Comment: what you are expecting with this code?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: First thing to mention - do not use string concatenation for building SQL queries. In your case, `My_StartDate` being a `DateTime`, makes this code SQL-injection-safe, but it is definitely a good idea to start using good practices and approaches.

Answer (score 2):

My_EndDate.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy")

Change it to correct format
 My_EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: would also go with ISO yyyy/MM/dd, UK dates are unreliable when SQL defaults to US format